# GhostScript command works in terminal but not in php script

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagick

I'm on Macos Big Sur version 11.2.3 with ghostscript 9.53, Imagick 7 php 7.2 . Every time imagick tries to read a pdf it returns PDFDelegateFailed.

```
PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library 9.53] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' '-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-VDP6hC8_eW6UjnfToLeyb_-zuhwCyhJ5%d' '-f/var/tmp/magick-lwCvBwuc8_ANVSR-PrGJmRaimOGGQPx3' '-f/var/tmp/magick-1RNOxrVIiW_7zQDUcbYYD2TUGVNxRWnu': (null)' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/676
```

I tried to execute the same error command in my terminal with full path it worked

```
gs -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 
'-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' 
'-sOutputFile=/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/b.png' '-f/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/a.pdf' 
'-f/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/a.pdf'
```

When i try to execute it in a simple exec php script it doesn't work anymore, worse i can't get any output from the command.

```
exec("/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3_1/bin/gs -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 
'-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' 
'-sOutputFile=/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/b.png' '-f/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/a.pdf' 
'-f/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/a.pdf' 2>&1",$output);


//exec("php -v",$output);

var_dump($output);
```

I already tried :

- change tmp file for imagick
- chmod lib folders
- reinstall imagick, ghostscript
- restart php-fpm,nginx,reboot
- downgrade ghostscript and imageMagick
- I have set in ImageMagick policy.xml rights to read and write ...

My server works well on linux with the same code but impossible to dev locally on macos

If you have any idea don't hesitate,

UPDATE :

The php script works with gs fullpath , i tried to modify delegates.xml gs path to full path but the problem still occurs on my server.

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the command so you'll see error messages.

Comment: If `gs` isn't in the standard `$PATH`, use the full path of the command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

exec("/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3_1/bin -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 
'-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' 
'-sOutputFile=/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/b.png' '-f/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/a.pdf' 
'-f/Users/leguillou/Desktop/test/a.pdf 2>&1'",$output);

I tried with this command but it doesn't seems to work, am i missing something?

Comment: It shouldn't be inside the single quotes.

Comment: It should be `a.pdf' 2>&1"`

Comment: Please post the PHP script as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar i get an error now i did an update in the original post

Comment: You shouldn't have any newlines in the command string.

Comment: Edit your ImageMagick delegates.xml file to put the full path to gs in all the PS/PDF/EPS etc lines.

Comment: The php script works now with the full path but even with the modified delegate.xml i get the same error on my server, i tried multiple syntax to the path am i missing something?   ```command="/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3_1/bin/gs```and ```command="&quot;/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3_1/bin/gs&quot; ``` I added the full path to all ps pdf eps lines

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using the full path. Worked for me. Previously, it worked in shell using just program name, but php was not seeing it even after apache restart.